# need to fill the non-null values to NaN based on column name

Tags: pandas

[image] here  need to update the non-null values of the columns values where specific text contains want to make them to nan values based on the column names. attached image for you reference.

Comment: You want to make the value NaN if it is the same as the column name?

Comment: like that or may not. having some string

Comment: Please be more specific on which values you want to replace

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following dataset

[image]

**Replace column name with nan**. But this won't replace any other string e.g. X0 contains value oth.

```
df.apply(lambda s: s.replace({s.name: np.nan}))
```

[image]

**Replace all string with nan**

```
df.apply(lambda s: pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce'))
```

[image]

**Replace all string with nan on subset of columns**

```
COLS = ['X0', 'X2']
df.apply(lambda s: pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce') if s.name in COLS else s)
```

[image]

**Note:** I have used pandas apply function but same result can be achieved with for loop